# Django Hierarchy Permissions

Tags: python, django, django-permissions

I want to have hierarchical level permissions in my Django Applications.

For example:- Consider there are 4 levels -

```
Admin
Sub-admin(CountryLevel(CL) Admin)
sub-sub-admin(StateLevel(SL) Admin)
And then normal Users(U).
```

Admins will create CL, in return CL will create SL, and SL will finally onboard the users. The end goal is to onboard the users.

Admins have the access to apply CRUD operation on any user. CL should have access to those users(objects) which were onboarded(created) by the CL created SLs. In return, SL should have access to only those users(objects) onboarded(created) by him. **Also, a user can get himself registered directly without any admins involved. In such case, the user shall have access to his own application.**

How can I achieve such tree-level like permissions?

The solution that I can think of is (but not sure about it):-

I've updated `auth_group` table and added `parent_id` into it. Following is the schema.

```
id, group_name, parent_id
```

The significance of `parent_id` is to create a tree-like structure of the groups. The number of groups created is equal to the height of the tree. For eg consider following structure:-

```
id, group_name, parent_id

1 , admin, 0
2, CL, 1
3, SL, 2
```

Now when any user is created(onboarded), I'll assign an `SL group_id`, which will be added to `auth_user_groups` table.

Now, I want to ask the following questions

1) How do I manage hierarchy-level permission of the groups, ie SL should only be able to access users onboarded by him, CL should be able to access all the users onboarded by the SLs created by him and so on.

2) (Not sure I'm thinking correctly or not) Now, since I've assigned a group SL to all the users onboarded by the SL, will the user be able to access each other information, being part of the same group?

3) For the users who are onboarde directly(ie not via any SL), I shall not be mapping them to any group. Right?

Comment: [`django-guardian`](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: A small example would be very helpful.

Comment: If you click the link in my comment, you'll find a sample project.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - If I need to make a dedicated OAuth2 Server as a service, how shall the permissions be managed by the OAuth2 Server?

Comment: Well, I see & understand how to assign object-level permissions. One quick question, please. How do I create a hierarchy of groups? And when assigning the object permission to the lowest level group, how will the parent groups be assigned the permission to access the same object. OR should I manually assign it on each of those parent groups?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - Any lead on this would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you find any suitable solution for this problem? Since I am also facing a similar issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Django already allows for a Group, User permissions which we can customize for our needs.

- Create the groups you need (form the admin panel for example, or by following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250352/in-django-how-do-you-programmatically-create-a-group-with-permissions?answertab=votes#tab-top).):

  1. 'country-admin-group`
  2. 'state-admin-group'
  3. 'user-group'
- Create custom permissions for your user groups and add them accordingly:

  ```
  from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
  from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  from your_app_name.models import CustomUserModel

  ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(CustomUserModel)
  permission_sl = Permission.objects.create(
      codename='can_add_sl_user',
      name='Can add SL user',
      content_type=ct
  )
  permission_user = Permission.objects.create(
      codename='can_add_simple_user',
      name='Can add simple user',
      content_type=ct
  )
  ...
  cl_group = Groups.get(name='country-admin-group')
  cl_group.permissions.add(permission_sl)
  cl_group,permissions.add(permission_user)

  sl_group = Groups.get(name='state-admin-group')
  sl_group,permissions.add(permission_user)
  ...
  ```
- Create views (and the corresponding urls) for each type of user.
  Personally I prefer to use class based views when applicable. We will control the access to each view with the [`method_decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) and [`permission_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) decorators:

  ```
  from django.http import HttpResponse
  from django.views import View

  class CountryAdminView(View):

      @login_required
      def list(self, request):
          """
          Can access only users created by him
          """
          content = Users.objects.filter(parent_id=request.user.id)
          return HttpResponse(content)

      @method_decorator(@permission_required('your_app_name.can_add_sl_user'))
      def create(self, request):
         ...
         Logic for creating an SL admin user.

      ...
  ```

Keep in mind that the above is a simplified example to set you in the path to the solution.

---

As @BurhanKhalid points out, you can skip a part of the above by using [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/tree/0edaf95095f9be792d4fb6eee9ef97ccaa5f70b5).

You can also use [django-role-permissions](https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-role-permissions) to define per user roles and add permissions to those roles.

Comment: The main thing which is missing is the hierarchy of the users? How would Level0 user views all the users created by the subordinate levels.?

Comment: "How do I create a hierarchy of groups? And when assigning the object permission to the lowest level group, how will the parent groups be assigned the permission to access the same object. OR should I manually assign it on each of those parent groups?"

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast For your 1st comment: In a view, `return MyCustomUsers.objects.all()`...
For the 2nd comment, the hierarchy will be manually created (see the answer). For the self "onboarded" users, you could define a group a `self-admitted-users` group and every level of admin can be a member of that group as well...

Comment: Okay. I guess I didn't make myself clearly understood. On 1st comment, consider 3 Levels (0, 1, 2). L0 admin is making Level1 users. Now L1 admin is making L2 users. Now, since the L2 users(objects) were made by L1, I assigned the object level permission of L2 to L1. `How would L0 now view details of L2?`

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast If the L0 user is a superuser, he can access every kind of user. Differently, give the L0 users group every permission that you created. Similarly, give the L1 user group permission to view and create L2 and L3 users etc.

Comment: There can be multiple L0 users. And each user from L0 group can create its OWN L1 users, and subsequently, each L1 user can create its OWN L2 users. Now, L0 user needs to view all L2 users which were created by L0 owned L1 users. Hence a hierarchy. How do I create such hierarchical permission?

Comment: I can't give L0 users all the permissions of all the objects. What I've thought is while creating a new L2/L3 object, I'll be traversing(fetching) all its parent-users and assign the object to each parent programmatically.  Your thoughts?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast Please restrain yourself to one comment at a time.
Since you have a Super-Admin group (L0) they should have access to everything (they are not admins differently...). Also, you can access the objects following the correct `parent_id`s up or down the chain (you just need to think a way of doing it correctly for your needs, you are an enthusiast after all...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168044/discussion-between-pythonenthusiast-and-john-moutafis).