# How add user to a group when update and create a user

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-permissions

I created a bunch of groups fallowing this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250352/programmatically-create-a-django-group-with-permissions#:~:text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250352/programmatically-create-a-django-group-with-permissions#:%7E:text)
I subscribed the User class adding a choice field called "role". Basically, that means what role that user has. That way if a user has the role of "staff" . Thus It'll have permissions of the group staff. The problem is: I can't get django to respond the way I expected. I put a signal after saving that it should add the user to the group according to their role. The program looks like this:

```
# project/app/model.py

class User(AbstractUser):
    class Roles(models.IntegerChoices):
        SUPER = 0, _('SuperAdmins')
        COMPANY = 1, _('Company')
        UNITY = 2, _('Unity')
        STAFF = 3, _('Staff')

   role: Roles = models.IntegerField(choices=Roles.choices, default=Roles.STAFF, verbose_name=_("Role"))
```

My signal is like:

```
GROUPS = ['SuperAdmins', 'Company', 'Unity', 'Staff']
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user(sender: User, instance: User, created: bool, **kwargs) -> None:
    """
    This receiver function will set every staff pages that is created to the group staff.

    :param sender: the model that will trigger this receiver
    :param instance: the instance
    :param created: if it was already created
    :param kwargs:
    :return: None
    """
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name=GROUPS[instance.role])
        instance.groups.add(group)
    else:
        group = Group.objects.get(name=GROUPS[instance.role])
        instance.groups.add(group)
        print("update")
```

When I go to the admin page and I create a new user, everything works as expected. But when I edit the role of an existing user, it just prints the "update" fron the print function but nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post the solution here in case anyone encounters the same problem. Along with the contribution of @mtzd. I found a tip for the solution based on the description of a problem that was in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1925784/18600263. So the pos_save signal will be:

```
from django.db import transaction

GROUPS = ['SuperAdmins', 'Company', 'Unity', 'Staff']


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user(sender: User, instance: User, **kwargs) -> None:
    group = Group.objects.get(name=GROUPS[instance.role])
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: instance.groups.set([group], clear=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, when changing the user role it will be added to a new group (without being removed from the previous one). For example if the user is part of the group `Staff` initially and then its role changes to `Company` it will be added to the `Company` group. As the relationship between the `User` model and the `Group` model is a Many to Many relationship, the user won't be removed from the `Staff` group. To do that there are to ways (which are basically the same):

First option with  `clear` then `add`:

```py
if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name=GROUPS[instance.role])
        instance.groups.add(group)
    else:
        group = Group.objects.get(name=GROUPS[instance.role])
        instance.groups.clear() # Dissasociates any group the user belonged to
        instance.groups.add(group) # Adds the group
```

Second option with `set`:

```py
if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name=GROUPS[instance.role])
        instance.groups.add(group)
    else:
        group = Group.objects.get(name=GROUPS[instance.role])
        instance.groups.set([group], clear=True) # Dissasociates any group the user belonged to and sets the new group. clear=True is necessary here because otherwise the Group instances would be deleted
```

With all this, if you decide to go with the second option, you can go with `set` also for users that are being created:

```py
GROUPS = ['SuperAdmins', 'Company', 'Unity', 'Staff']
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user(sender: User, instance: User, **kwargs) -> None:
    """
    This receiver function will set every staff pages that is created to the group staff.

    :param sender: the model that will trigger this receiver
    :param instance: the instance
    :param kwargs:
    :return: None
    """
    group = Group.objects.get(name=GROUPS[instance.role])
    instance.groups.set([group], clear=True)
```

and thus you don't have to use the `created` param. For more info on `clear` and `set` you can read the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear and see how they can be used!

Comment: Yes, I got it! But, the problem is: it doesn't work when I want to update the user.